# How can extract multiple elements from a XML tree with a single #each iteration

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

My xml looks something like this:

```
<entry>
  <updated>2012-11-14T13:58:49-07:00</updated>
  <id im:id="557137623" im:bundleId="com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars">Some text</id>
  <title>Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd</title>
</entry>
<entry>
  <updated>2012-11-14T13:58:49-07:00</updated>
  <id im:id="557137623" im:bundleId="com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars">Some text</id>
  <title>Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd</title>
</entry>
```

I would like use Nokogiri to grab some data from the xml. Namely I am interested in the `im:id`, `im:bundleId` and the `<title>` from the xml above.

I have managed to get to the stage where this works:

```
xml.css("entry id").each do |entry|
   puts entry["im:id"]
   puts entry["im:bundleid"]
end
```

The problems is that to get `title` content I would have to iterate through `xml.css("entry title")` separately. Is there anyway of iterating through the entries and then pulling out the `id` data and the `title` in the same loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your example XML isn't correctly nested, so that needs to be fixed:

```
<root>
  <entry>
    <updated>2012-11-14T13:58:49-07:00</updated>
    <id im:id="557137623" im:bundleId="com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars">Some text</id>
    <title>Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <updated>2012-11-14T13:58:49-07:00</updated>
    <id im:id="557137623" im:bundleId="com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars">Some text</id>
    <title>Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd</title>
  </entry>
</root>
```

Then, this works:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<root>
  <entry>
    <updated>2012-11-14T13:58:49-07:00</updated>
    <id im:id="557137623" im:bundleId="com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars">Some text</id>
    <title>Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd</title>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <updated>2012-11-14T13:58:49-07:00</updated>
    <id im:id="557137623" im:bundleId="com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars">Some text</id>
    <title>Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd</title>
  </entry>
</root>
EOT

pp doc.search('entry').map{ |e|
  id = e.at('id')
  [
    id['id'],
    id['bundleId'],
    e.at('title').text
  ]
}
```

Which looks like:

```
[["557137623",
  "com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars",
  "Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd"],
["557137623",
  "com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars",
  "Angry Birds Star Wars - Rovio Entertainment Ltd"]]
```

This works because I'm walking through the `entry` tags. For each `entry`, I look for the `id` tag, and remember it, making it easy to look into it repeatedly for the `id` and `bundleID` parameters. Then it's a simple case of looking inside `e` for the `title` tag.

I'm sure it could be done using some funky XPath, but I'm mortal and like to keep it simple.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for. Just to make sure I understand - #search returns a nodeset which you are then iterating through. #at looks at each node in the nodeset for a specific element using a css selector? Will try this when I get home tonight and then (hopefully) accept the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `at` returns the first matching node. Think of the code as successively drilling down. When it finds an `<entry>` node of interest it peeks inside, then moves on. Ripping apart XML and HTML using the DOM and a parser has a steep learning curve at first but once you're over the hump it's pretty easy, and really powerful.

Comment: Quick follow up question. If I have xml structure like `<entry><im:price amount="0"></im:price></entry>` how do I get at the 0 in the amount attribute? In fact what is the meaning of the `im:` prefix?

Comment: Okay I found out that the prefix before the colon is an xml namespace and I dealt with it by calling `remove_namespaces!` on `doc` and then using the `#at` method with `'price'` as the argument as you outlined. Is there some way of searching namespaced elements more elegantly?